# Use Scene Builder in existing Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I have an existing Eclipse project with Java 8 and Maven. Now I want to create a window with Oracle's Scene Builder. How can I do that?

All the tutorials start with "Create a new JavaFX project". This doesn't help me. I want to work with my existing project.

Comment: Do you have e(fx)clipse (the Eclipse plugin) installed?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't saw the "Open with SceneBuilder" option because I've looked in the "Open With" menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just create a basic fxml file in your project hierarchy. Then right-click on it and choose "Open with SceneBuilder".

To create the file, if you have e(fx)clipse installed, you can do File -> New -> Other. Then under "JavaFX" choose "FXML document". Put in the name (*without* the `.fxml` extension), and choose your root element. Then once the file is created, close it, right-click on it in the package explorer, and open with SceneBuilder.

If you don't have e(fx)clipse, I think you can still do this; just create a blank file (File -> New -> File) and name it *with* the fxml extension. Then, again, right-click and choose "Open with SceneBuilder". (The only thing I am not sure about is whether this option is available without e(fx)clipse.)